# comparing the mail data in two data frames

Tags: r

I have two data frames having id and email in both data frames and i want to check if the email is consistent in new data frame as compared to old data frame.

df1 = df_old
df2 = df_new

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID =c("DEV2962","KTN2252","ANA2719","ITI2624","DEV2698","HRT2921","KTN2633","KTN2624","ANA2548","ITI2535","DEV2732","HRT2837","ERV2951","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210"),
                  city=c("del","mum","nav","pun","bang","chen","triv","vish","del","mum","bang","vish","bhop","kol","noi","gurg"),
                  email = c("akash.dev@gmail.com","rahul.singh@gmail.com",NA,NA,NA,NA,"sanu.ali@gmail.com","kunal.singh@gmail.com","lakhan.tomar@gmail.com","praveen.thakur@gmail.com","sarman.ali@gmail.com","zuber.khan@gmail.com","giriraj.singh@gmail.com","lokesh.sharma@gmail.com","pooja.pawar@gmail.com","nikita.sharma@gmail.com"),
                  Name= c("dev,akash","singh,rahul","abbas,salman","lal,ram","singh,nkunj","garg,prabal","ali,sanu","singh,kunal","tomar,lakhan","thakur,praveen","ali,sarman","khan,zuber","singh,giriraj","sharma,lokesh","pawar,pooja","sharma,nikita"))

df2 <- data.frame(ID =c("DEV2962","KTN2152","ANA2719","ITs2624","DEV2698","HRT2921","KTN2633","KTN2624","ANA2548","ITI2535","DEV2732","HRT2837","ERV2951","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210"),
                  city=c("del","mum","nav","pun","bang","chen","ddgy","vish","del","mum","bang","vish","bhol","nhus","huay","gurg"),
                  email = c("akash.dev@gmail.com","dhumh.singh@gmail.com",NA,NA,"shoayahau",NA,"sanu.ali@gmail.com","kunal.nhil@gmail.com","lakhan.tomar@gmail.com","praveen.thakur@gmail.com","sarman.ali@gmail.com","zuber.khan@gmail.com","giriraj.singh@gmail.com","lokesh.sharma@gmail.com","pooja.pawar@gmail.com","nikita.sharma@gmail.com"))

df1 %>% 
  inner_join(df2, by="ID") %>% 
  select(ID, contains("email")) %>% 
  mutate(consistent = ifelse(email.x == email.y, "consistent", "Inconsistent")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = contains("email"), values_to = "email"
  ) %>% 
  select(ID, email, consistent) %>% 
  data.frame()
```

The output should be new data frame like below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 %>% 
  inner_join(df2, by="ID") %>%
  rename("email_old" = "email.x", "email_new" = "email.y") %>%
  mutate(across(contains("email"), tolower)) %>%
  select(ID, contains("email")) %>% 
  mutate(consistent = if_else(email_new == email_old, "Consistent", "Inconsistent"))


        ID                email_old                email_new   consistent
1  DEV2962      akash.dev@gmail.com      akash.dev@gmail.com   Consistent
2  ANA2719                     <NA>                     <NA>         <NA>
3  DEV2698                     <NA>                shoayahau         <NA>
4  HRT2921                     <NA>                     <NA>         <NA>
5  KTN2633       sanu.ali@gmail.com       sanu.ali@gmail.com   Consistent
6  KTN2624    kunal.singh@gmail.com     kunal.nhil@gmail.com Inconsistent
7  ANA2548   lakhan.tomar@gmail.com   lakhan.tomar@gmail.com   Consistent
8  ITI2535 praveen.thakur@gmail.com praveen.thakur@gmail.com   Consistent
9  DEV2732     sarman.ali@gmail.com     sarman.ali@gmail.com   Consistent
10 HRT2837     zuber.khan@gmail.com     zuber.khan@gmail.com   Consistent
11 ERV2951  giriraj.singh@gmail.com  giriraj.singh@gmail.com   Consistent
12 KTN2542  lokesh.sharma@gmail.com  lokesh.sharma@gmail.com   Consistent
13 ANA2813    pooja.pawar@gmail.com    pooja.pawar@gmail.com   Consistent
14 ITI2210  nikita.sharma@gmail.com  nikita.sharma@gmail.com   Consistent
```

Comment: also if i want to convert all email to lower case then check if they are consistent...???

Comment: see edit to convert both to lower